# Why do these two pointer subtractions give different results?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
char* p = new char[2];
long* pi = (long*) p;
assert(p == pi);         // OK

char* p1 = &p[1];
long* pi1 = (long*) p1;
assert(p1 == pi1);       // OK

int d = p1 - p;
int d1 = pi1 - pi;
assert(d == d1);         // No :(
```

After this runs, I get `d == 1` and `d1 == 0`, although `p1 == pi1` and `p == pi` (I checked this in the debugger). Is this undefined behavior?

Comment: If you look at the disassembly, `pi1 - pi` produces a subtraction followed by a right-shift by 2 bits. (on MSVC) That right-shift is obviously to divide by `sizeof(long)` which of course truncates to 0 with a difference of only 1. Whether this behavior is defined or not I don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have pointed, this is undefined behavior.  However, there is a very simple explanation for what you are seeing.

The difference between pointers is the number of elements, not the number of bytes between them.

pi and pi1 both point to longs, but the address pointed to by pi1 is only one byte further than pi.  Presuming longs are 4 bytes long, the difference in the addresses, 1, divided by the size of the element, 4, is 0.

Another way of thinking of this is you could imagine the compiler would generate code equivalent to this for calculating d1:

```
int d1 = ((BYTE*)pi1 - (BYTE*)pi)/sizeof(long).
```

Answer (score 5):

The difference between two pointers is undefined if the pointers do not point to the same array, or if the pointers were typecast from pointers to an unrelated type.

Also, the difference is not in bytes but is in the number of elements.

In your second case the difference is 1 byte, but it is being divided by sizeof(long). Note that because this is undefined behavior, absolutely any answer here would be correct.

Comment: Man, I am laughing my back off looking at your avatar :) This is one of a brilliant idea :)))

Comment: What section is it in that says you can't do pointer arithmetic on pointers casted from an unrelated type

Comment: @SethCarnegie, I can't point to anything specific, and in fact I may be mistaken. I thought that the type cast itself generated UB, especially in this case since it's unaligned for the type.

Comment: Ah, you're right. (For anyone who wants to know, I think that is spelled out in §5.2.10.7)

Answer (score 2):

Reinterpreting the underlying type of a pointer does not change its address. But pointer arithmetics yields different result depending on the pointer type. So what you have described here is perfectly correct and that is what I would expect. See [pointer arithmetics](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html).

Answer (score 0):

Its doing integer (long) pointer arithmetic for `pi1 - pi`;

If `p1` were `&p[4]` you'll see that it prints `1` for `d1` while the difference is actually 4 bytes. This is because `sizeof (long)` = 4 bytes.

Comment: The size of `long` is platform dependent and therefore the difference might be `0` even if `p1` points to `&p[4]` (or it might be `4` or something else). As a matter of fact many 64bit platforms have 8byte `long`. IIRC there even exist platforms where `sizeof(long)==1` (`char` is e.g. `64bit` on those)