# behaviour of pointers when typecasted

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do these two pointer subtractions give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185171/why-do-these-two-pointer-subtractions-give-different-results)

```
char arr[] = "stackoverflow";
char *p1 = arr;
char *p2 = arr + 3;
printf("%d",  (int*)p2 - (int*)p1);
```

it's answer is 0..Can you explain why is it so ?

Comment: Please make sure the code is compilable first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `p2 - p1` is `<  sizeof (int)`. So `(int *) p2 - (int *) p1 == 0`, the number of `int` elements between the two pointers.

Comment: thnx man ,I got it !! woo I just missed da part :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're invoking implementation-defined/undefined behaviour.  An `int` is probably of size 4 on your platform, so at least one of those pointers is not correctly aligned.

In practice, it's probably because the compiler is doing something like `(p2 / 4) - (p1 / 4)` under the hood.

Comment: ...or even `(p2-p1) & ~3` :-)

Comment: Where does ~3 come from?

Comment: Isn't it just flat-out *undefined* behaviour? You're attempting pointer arithmetic on invalid pointers, period.

Comment: @Kylo: I'm implying that the compiler throws away the 2 lsbs of each value.  Although actually division would make more sense here, so I've edited the answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not sure.  I'm hedging my bets now!

Comment: Hah, coward :-) I'll take the firmer position that neither `arr` nor `arr + 3` are valid `int *` and thus arithmetic with them is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably meant to do is:

```
printf("%d",  (int)(p2 - p1));
```

But this does not even require a conversion because the difference between two pointers returns a signed integral type (`ptrdiff_t`) so you can leave out the typecast and change `"%d"` to `"%td"`.

Comment: If you omit the cast you need to use the `t` length modifier: `printf("%td", p2 - p1);` The `%d` is for an `int` argument.