# What is the logic behind the below program?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int t[4] = { 8, 4, 2, 1 };
  int *p1 = t + 2, *p2 = p1 - 1;
  p1++; 
  cout << *p1 - t[p1 - p2] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

here p1 = 0x00000007c2affa24[**1**] 
p2 = 0x00000007c2affa1c[**4**] (address and value) but **p1-p2 = 2**

```
output is -1
```

I am not able to understand this logic, Please help me.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic takes the pointee type into consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185171/why-do-these-two-pointer-subtractions-give-different-results

Comment: @Bathsheba@Aakash Deep@Killzone Kid@S_Madankar. Thank you very much..

Comment: Protips (1) SO only lets you tag one person. It's me because I was first. (2) You shoul accept an answer if it told you what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please look through the comments for solution

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int t[4] = { 8, 4, 2, 1 };

  int *p1 = t + 2, *p2 = p1 - 1;  
  // p1 holds the address of t[2],  p2 holds the address of t[1]  

  p1++;   
  //Now, p1 holds the address of t[3]  

  cout << *p1 - t[p1 - p2] << endl;  // We need to pointer arithmetic  
  //Here p1 has the value 1,
  //t[(t+3)-(t+1)] = t[2] which is 2,
  //So, the answer would be 1-2 = -1
  return 0;
}
```

Have a look to this website
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm

Comment: Have an upvote, this is a nice clear way of answering this.

Answer (score 5):

Your `cout` is equivalent to

`std::cout << t[3] - t[2] << endl;`.

Furthermore `t[3] - t[2]` is `-1`.

`p1` starts off as `t + 2`, and `p1++` increments it to `t + 3`. So `*p1` is `t[3]` at the point of calling `std::cout`.

`p1 - p2` is `(t + 3) - (t + 1)` at the point of evaluation which is 2. Note that pointer arithmetic is in units of `sizeof` your type, **not** 1. That accounts for the difference in the addresses being a multiple of the `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: _"Note that pointer arithmetic is in units of sizeof your type, not 1"_: in my opinion, this is the most important part of your answer.

Answer (score 5):

> int t[4] = { 8, 4, 2, 1 };

```
{ 8, 4, 2, 1 }
  ^
  t
```

> int *p1 = t + 2;

```
{ 8, 4, 2, 1 }
        ^
        p1
```

> int *p2 = p1 - 1;

```
{ 8, 4, 2, 1 }
     ^  ^
     p2 p1
```

> p1++;

```
{ 8, 4, 2, 1 }
     ^     ^
     p2    p1
```

(*p1 - p2 => 2*)

> cout << *p1 - t[p1 - p2] << endl;

```
1 - t[2] => 1 - 2 => -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I will explain the logic in the form of comments in following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int t[4] = { 8, 4, 2, 1 };
  int *p1 = t + 2, *p2 = p1 - 1; /* p1 will point to 3rd element of array i.e. t[2]=2 and p2 will point to 2nd element i.e. t[1]=4 */
  p1++; // now p1 will point to 4th element i.e t[3]=1 
  cout << *p1 - t[p1 - p2] << endl; /* So 1-t[2] = 1 - 2 = -1 Since array difference is return in terms of Number of element which can be occupied in that memory space . So, instead of returning 8 , p1-p2 will give 2 */ 
  return 0;
}
```